# Handling MemoryError in my Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a web crawler that crawls wikipedia and stores fetched data (title, content and links) inside an MySQL database, with beautifulsoup and pymysql libraries. After running the code a lot of times I managed to fix all the errors that were causing my program to terminate. Now the problem I have is with MemoryError. Any idea how to avoid this? Everyone online say that you can't handle this error by making an exception, or at least is not good practice. All the solutions about this online were given for specific programs with third party libraries so I couldn't make any sense. The program terminates and the error appears around after 2000 loops.

```
import socket
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql
import re


#for recursion depth
from requests import Timeout, RequestException
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(80000)
pages=set()
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='somepsw', db='mysql', charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("USE searchenginedb2")


def store(title, content, link):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO websites (title, content, link) VALUES (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")", (title, content, link))
    cur.connection.commit()

def getLinks(pageUrl):
    global pages
    try:
        html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org" + pageUrl, timeout=10)#timeout for timeouterror
    except HTTPError:
        print("HTTP ERROR")
    except URLError:
        print("URLERROR")
    except socket.timeout:
        print("SOCKERT TIMEOUT")


    try:
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    except UnboundLocalError:
        print("UnboundLocalError")


    try:
        #print(bsObj.h1.get_text())
        title = bsObj.find("h1").get_text()

        content = bsObj.find("div", {"id": "mw-content-text"}).find("p").get_text()
        #print(bsObj.find(id="mw-content-text").findAll("p")[0])
        store(title, content,"http://en.wikipedia.org" + pageUrl)
        #print(bsObj.find(id="ca-edit").find("span").find("a").attrs['href'])
    except AttributeError:
        print("Attribute Error: Page missing!")
    except UnboundLocalError:
        print("UnboundLocalError")

    except HTTPError as err:
        print("URL that generated the error code: ", pageUrl)
        print("Error code:", err.code)
        print("Error description:", err.reason)
    except Timeout:
        print("URL that generated the error code: ", pageUrl)
        print("Error description: Session timed out.")
    except ConnectionError:
        print("URL that generated the error code: ", pageUrl)
        print("Error description: Socket error timed out.")
    except RequestException as e:
        print (e)



#for avoiding crawling the same page twice.
    try:

        for link in bsObj.findAll("a", href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)")):
            if 'href' in link.attrs:
                if link.attrs['href'] not in pages:
                    # We have encountered a new page
                    newPage = link.attrs['href']
                    print("http://en.wikipedia.org"+ newPage)
                    pages.add(newPage)
                    getLinks(newPage)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        print("UnboundLocalError")


getLinks("")
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/paula/PycharmProjects/BookTests/StoringData/ownWikipedia.py", line 83, in getLinks
    getLinks(newPage)
  File "C:/Users/paula/PycharmProjects/BookTests/StoringData/ownWikipedia.py", line 83, in getLinks
    getLinks(newPage)
  File "C:/Users/paula/PycharmProjects/BookTests/StoringData/ownWikipedia.py", line 83, in getLinks
    getLinks(newPage)
  [Previous line repeated 984 more times]
  File "C:/Users/paula/PycharmProjects/BookTests/StoringData/ownWikipedia.py", line 40, in getLinks
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 225, in __init__
    markup, from_encoding, exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)):
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 205, in prepare_markup
    exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 366, in __init__
    for encoding in self.detector.encodings:
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 264, in encodings
    self.chardet_encoding = chardet_dammit(self.markup)
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 34, in chardet_dammit
    return chardet.detect(s)['encoding']
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\chardet\__init__.py", line 38, in detect
    detector.feed(byte_str)
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\chardet\universaldetector.py", line 211, in feed
    if prober.feed(byte_str) == ProbingState.FOUND_IT:
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\chardet\charsetgroupprober.py", line 71, in feed
    state = prober.feed(byte_str)
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\chardet\hebrewprober.py", line 227, in feed
    byte_str = self.filter_high_byte_only(byte_str)
  File "C:\Users\paula\PycharmProjects\BookTests\venv\lib\site-packages\chardet\charsetprober.py", line 63, in filter_high_byte_only
    buf = re.sub(b'([\x00-\x7F])+', b' ', buf)
  File "C:\Users\paula\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
MemoryError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: you should probably figure out why you are having to catch `UnboundLocalError` and fix that

Comment: `sys.setrecursionlimit(80000)` is also probably a bad idea.

Comment: What's the point of doing this when you can simply [download all of wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#English-language_Wikipedia)?

Comment: for the `UnboundLocalError` catch I had to do this because I was getting the error: `local variable referenced before assignment`. After implementing the try catch statement at the `BeautifulSoup` object, that error disappeared. Not sure if this is the best way though. For the `setrecursionlimit(80000)` I did it in order to store more links in my database, since without it I only stored around 990. Again not the best way but can't think of anything else.

Comment: Wikipedia is easy to crawl. If I manage to figure out all the errors and being able to crawl wikipedia, I can move on to different websites. Plus this is for a mini search engine i am going to create for my Bachelor thesis.

Comment: @Pavlosskevofylax: All of your `UnboundLocalError` errors are because you keep catching exceptions and ignoring them to keep trying to run, even though you didn't do what you needed to do to continue (e.g. `urlopen` fails, so `html` isn't assigned, but you keep going anyway, so of course trying to use `html` later fails). Silencing them more isn't making things better. If you can't handle an exception, either don't catch it, or at the very least, after printing the log message, return from the function rather than trying to bull your way through.

Comment: i'd use the [wikipedia api](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia) if was you..